# Repair corrupt bin .dll in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

I realize some DLLs in my application have been marked corrupt by the application in visual studio,

I am using Visual Studio 2013 working on a web application project, i have closed and restarted the application yet the issue still persist, the application still builds and runs but throw some errors, but upon uploading to server using filezilla ftpclient, the corrupt files doesnt show on ftpclient, i have deleted the bin folder and add a new one from my back, but it still shows corrupt whenever those DLLs comes to visual studio environment.

[image]

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that those files exist?  Why does VS think they're corrupt?  Are you uploading the results of a VS publish, as VS is unlikely to publish files that it thinks are corrupt.

Comment: When you started with this project , was that on visual studio 2013 ? or on a other version ?

Comment: I just found out that marked corrupt files are always shown whenever i clean solution, my question now is, can i build and deploy a project without cleaning solution? thanks @christutty, no, i havent publish files yet, i was only rebuilding and cleaning solution before it happens.

Comment: @creator, i was been handed over the project, i wouldn't know the version of visual studio the project was created with

Comment: @Creator, I just realized that the project was created using Iron speed 8.0.2 tool with visual studio 2010, now i am running the project on visual studio 2013, i dont also know whether that could cause this. Thanks